# is it possible to change the start of a path for multiple json objects?

Tags: octopus-deploy

I am in the process of putting a project on Octopus deploy. There are a lot of Json variables that need to be changed depending on the environment.

In particular, I need to change many "path" variables that point to a shared drive. For debugging and UAT I want to change all these to a local path.

**Eg:** 10 Json objects with a value `"path": "sharedDrive\uniquePath\\..."` changed to `"path": "C:\\uniquePath\\..."`

Is this possible with Octopus deploy?

Comment: You could use variables in octopus, is that what you are looking for? I could explain.

Comment: [variable substitution in files](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/configuration-features/substitute-variables-in-files)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I had looked at this and it didn't seem ideal for debugging without having two sets of configuration? this wasn't really wanted. what I did instead was change the json to have a "rootPath" (which can be changed in octopus) then the rest of the unique path ends append to the "root path". My particular problem is probably not something that is encountered too often unless you inherit badly designed code/configuration.

Comment: Normally for the purpose I would have an override configuration per deployment environment. So when you debugging locally you use the base config without override and the variable substitution is in the overrides.